# Report subtotals without grouping

Tags: reporting-services

Might be easier to show what I am trying to return and then explain.

```
REGION  STATE  SALES
------  -----  -----
WEST    WA     $ 200
EAST    VA     $ 175
WEST    CA     $ 100
EAST    NY     $  50
NORTH   MI     $  25
NORTH   WI     $  20
  WEST SUBTOTAL: $300
  EAST SUBTOTAL: $225
 NORTH SUBTOTAL: $ 45
    GRAND TOTAL:$570
```

While the example above isn't my exact business case, it's close enough to simplify the question.

So, using the sample data above, my report can be ran by one or more regions. In this example, I ran it for regions west, east and south. The report sorts the detail data by total sales, with the highest sales at the top. Following the detail data, I'd like to get a subtotal of the regions' totals. If I ran for two regions, then I'd get two subtotal lines. Then finally, a grand total.

This would be easy if I was grouping by region, but I'm not; I want the detail to remain sorted by sales regardless of region. How can I achieve this? The tricky part is the dynamic number of subtotal lines.

I'm running SSRS 2012.

Comment: Can you please advise which specific version of SSRS you're using?

Comment: @IanPreston Sorry. I completely forget to add that by the time I finished typing everything else out. I've edited the original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in the one table based on your existing Dataset using an **Adjacent Group** based on *REGION*.

Say you have a simple table like:

[image]

To add the *REGION* subtotals, right click on the detail row and select **Add Group** -> **Adjacent Below...**:

[image]

The end result should look something like:

[image]

i.e. the group row is directly after all the detail rows.

In my case I set the expression to `=Fields!REGION.Value & " Sub Total:"` and set the new group to sort by `=Sum(Fields!SALES.Value)` from high to low.

Seems to work as required, give or take some formatting:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Never used the Adjacent Group feature.