# SSRS Adjacent groups subtotals

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report, reporting

I'm having issues to show subtotals for adjacent groups which are inside of a parent group. The grouping structure is something like this:

```
ParentGroup1 : 20

    ChildGroup1 : 8
    ChildGroup2 : 8
    *TOTAL FOR ChildGroup3* : 4
        ChildGroup3.1 : 2
        ChildGroup3.1 : 2

ParentGroup2
```

I already have the grouping structure , with three adjacent groups for each of the child groups.
When I try to add a total for ChildGroup3 , it adds me row before the group with the expressions needed. However, it doesn't take into account the filters that I have for ChildGroup3. It shows me the values , grouping by ParentGroup1. This meaning that it shows me  *TOTAL FOR ChildGroup3* : 20 , instead of 4.

Any idea of how should I add the Total rows so that it sums 4, instead of 20? Adding totals for the group doesn't work as expected. 
Also, I can't add a footer to the group, since the options appears disabled every time I add a new group.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I already tried removing parent group and adding subtotals, but still doesn't work. I also tried applying some filters to the subtotal expression so that it filters out the other groups values, but that doesn't work either. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an additional parent group for ChildGroup3. The additional parent group was created based on the value of a calculated field that I added to the Dataset , to differentiate the items within this group from the other items of the other groups.Then, for this new parent group it allowed me to add a header and I could add my subtotal there :)

Comment: Got the idea from this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17682757/report-subtotals-without-grouping